# Order Result in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

In MySQL , my sql is like following

```
SELECT * , IF( `Word` = 'sim', 1, IF( `Word` LIKE 'sim%', 2, IF( `Word` LIKE '%sim', 4, 3 ) ) ) AS `sort`
FROM `dblist`
WHERE `Word` LIKE '%sim%'
ORDER BY `sort` , `Word`
```

This sql is not working in SQlite. I want to do result order.

```
SELECT * FROM dblist where word like 'sim' or word like 'sim%' or word like '%sim%' or word like '%sim'
```

equal sim is a frist , sim% is second and %sim% is a thrid and then %sim is a last.

Currently I can't sort like mysql in sqlite. How to change sql to order the result ?

Comment: "This sql is not working" - Can you post the error you get? It's much easier for us to solve your problem when you tell us what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) instead of [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) as the latter is not supported by SQLite. Here is the SQL you need:

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN `Word` = 'sim' THEN 1
         WHEN `Word` LIKE 'sim%' THEN 2
         WHEN `Word` LIKE '%sim' THEN 4
         ELSE 3
    END `sort`
FROM `dblist`
WHERE `Word` LIKE '%sim%'
ORDER BY `sort` , `Word`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * , case when `Word` = 'sim' then 1 else case when `Word` LIKE 'sim%' then 2 else case when `Word` LIKE '%sim' then 4 else 3 end end end as sort
FROM `dblist`
WHERE `Word` LIKE '%sim%'
ORDER BY `sort` , `Word
```